# How to solve Zimbra zmconfigd not running/starting

Tags: zimbra

my server with `zimbra` is stopped `zmconfigd` service and I can not lift it I have done everything I indicate below.

```
su - zimbra -c "zmcontrol stop"
pkill zimbra
killall zimbra
/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmfixperms -e -v
su - zimbra -c "zmcontrol start"
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may be difficult for others to help with without further info. The details are probably inside your error log. `/var/log/zimbra.log `

Comment: File "/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmconfigd", line 222, in <module> myState.getMtaConfig (myConfig.configFile), File "/opt/zimbra/common/lib/jylibs/state.py", line 347, in getMtaConfig self.mtaconfig.load (cf, self), File "/opt/zimbra/common/lib/jylibs/mtaconfig.py", line 260, in load val = state.lookUpConfig (fields [2], fields [3 ])File "/opt/zimbra/common/lib/jylibs/state.py", line 369, in lookUpConfig lines = [self.transform (l) .strip () for l in open (tmpfile, 'r'). readlines () if self.transform

Comment: (l) .strip ()], Sleeping.Configuration inconsistency detected ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/zimbra/conf/zmconfigd/postfix_content_filter.cf')

Comment: Permission denied. The zimbra user may not have privileges you start and stop the service.

Comment: I am having the same problem, Zimbra 8.5.1 on Ubuntu 12 LTS.  Everything working for over a year or more without making any changes, now zmconfigd fails.  If I figure it out before I'm forced to replace the server with an up-to-date version, I'll post an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to missing `which` or `netcat` package. Especially likely on minimal LXC container images of CentOS which often do not include `which` and Zimbra packages do not depend on it, which IMHO is a bug.

Just `yum install which`.